# ¿Cómo respaldar todas las bases de datos de un usuario?

Tags: mysql, bash

Tengo un usuario mysql con varias bases de datos. ¿Cómo podría respaldar cada una en un archivo .sql?

Actualmente utilizo un script de bash para hacer esto, pero le tengo que indicar el nombre de la base de datos que quiero respaldar.

```
mysqldump --user=$user --password=$password --host=$host $db_name > $backup_path/$db_name-$date.sql
```

Pero tengo que hacer esto para cada una de las bases manualmente. ¿Hay alguna manera de obtener todas las bases de datos?

Comment: Puedes hacer una consulta al `information_schema` para obtener todas las bases de datos y tirarlo a un archivo de texto. Luego usando bash vas leyendo cada línea del archivo para generar tu comando `mysqldump`

Comment: Hola, ¿te sirvió el `script`?

Comment: Hola @akko, por favor, si la respuesta te valió puntúa la respuesta como correcta, si no es así, amplia tu pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo aquí un pequeño script que seguro que te vale.

Un requisito de este script es que el usuario de `MySQL` se pueda conectar sin necesidad de contraseña al sistema, eso se hace fácilmente con un `.my.cnf`

```
EXCLUDED_DATABASE=("information_schema" "performance_schema" "sys")

function arrayContains() {
        local needle="$1"
        printf "%s\n" ${EXCLUDED_DATABASE[@]} | grep -q "^$needle$"
}

mkdir -p /root/bbdd_data
mkdir -p /root/bbdd_log

for SCRIPT_DATABASE in `mysql -Bse 'show databases'`; do

    arrayContains $SCRIPT_DATABASE
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        continue
    fi

    mysqldump --force --opt --verbose --compress --triggers --routines --lock-tables=false --single-transaction --result-file=/root/bbdd_data/$SCRIPT_DATABASE $SCRIPT_DATABASE > /dev/null 2> /root/bbdd_log/$SCRIPT_DATABASE.log

    if [ ! -s /root/bbdd_data/$SCRIPT_DATABASE ]; then
        echo 'dump_file_empty' >> /root/bbdd_log/$SCRIPT_DATABASE.log
    fi

    gzip /root/bbdd_data/$SCRIPT_DATABASE;
done
```

Te explico un poco lo que hace:

1. El `show databases` nos da un listado de las bases de datos que puede ver ese usuario y nos devuelve un `array`
2. Verificamos que esa BBDD no se llame igual que las que queremos excluir (`arrayContains()`)
3. Hacemos el `dump` y le decimos donde guardar la `BBDD` y el log`del`dump` por si nos encontramos algún error al hacer la exportación.
4. Comprobamos que el fichero de dump no esté vacío. Si es así escribimos un error en el fichero de `log`
5. Hacemos un `gzip` para que ocupe poco.

Si aún así quieres poner el `user/pass` con agregar `--user=$user --password=$password` al `dump` te vale.

Si tienes dudas me dices.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo en una simple linea de bash puedes hacerlo

```
for DataB in `mysql -e "show databases" -u USUARIO -pCLAVE | grep -v Database`; do mysqldump -u USUARIO -pCLAVE $DataB > "$DataB.sql"; done
```